# Input only even numbers in textField Flutter

Tags: flutter, input, keyboard, numbers, textfield

so, is it way to do **TextFormField** where users only can insert even numbers? Now they can't type for example 12 and that's the problem.

```
                    child: TextFormField(
                      inputFormatters: [
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp("[1,3,5,7,9]"))
                      ],
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
```

Comment: Why is it a problem that they can't type "13?"

Comment: because i want let them to type only even numbers and 13 isn't even.

Comment: ```FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp("[3,5,7,9]"))```

line makes that they can't insert 3,5,7 and 9

Comment: Yeah, and you can't type "13" without typing "3." So, what's the problem? Your code works aside from forgetting that "1" is also an odd number

Comment: Oh sorry xd i mean 12, im dumm.. they can't type 12 and that's the problem

Comment: i edited the post now its fine i think

Comment: If you only want the overall number to be even, even if it contains odd digits, then you need to validate it when the user submits because that's the only way to tell when they've finished entering the number. `InputFormatter`s won't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The even or odd number can be tested by only looking at the last digit, which need to be even or odd too. So the Regex for odd number runs could be:

```
"$\s*(\d*[13579]\s*,\s*)*\d*[13579]$"
```

Use regrex expression as below

```
child: TextFormField(
                      inputFormatters: [
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp("$\s*(\d*[13579]\s*,\s*)*\d*[13579]$"))
                      ],
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
```

For to deny even number use below regrex expression

```
"$\s*(\d*[02468]\s*,\s*)*\d*[02468]$"
```

Comment: It says that it Expects an idintifier, i guess there is a mistake in this code

Comment: I tried the following:
 `"^\\s*(\\d*[13579]\\s*,\\s*)*\\d*[13579]\$"`. 
Now if i want to insert 12, it reset's the input after pressing 1.